How to Decode StreamingTextResponse from Vercel AI SDK in Nuxt.js API
I am following the Vercel AI SDK documentation https://sdk.vercel.ai/ (using nuxt.js). I have an API that queries and returns a StreamingTextResponse as text.
  // Ask OpenAI for a streaming chat completion given the prompt
  const result = await streamText({
    model: openai('gpt-3.5-turbo'),
    prompt: prompt,
    temperature: 0.75,
    frequencyPenalty: 1,
  });

  // Convert the response into a friendly text-stream
  const stream = result.toAIStream({
    onFinal(_) {},
  });

  const streamingResponse = new StreamingTextResponse(stream)
  return await streamingResponse.text()

To call the API, I make a fetch request on the page:
const response = await fetch('/api/ai', {
    ...
  });
text.value = await response.text();

However, the response is encoded like this:
0:"Dr"
0:"aco"
0:","
0:" the"
0:" dragon"
0:" protector"
0:","
0:" soared"
0:" through"
0:" the"
0:" skies"
0:","
0:" guarding"
0:" all"
0:" those"
0:" in"
0:" need"
0:" below"
...

How can I decode this?
